# Assign passport.js user data to socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, passport.js

I'm using `passport.js` to provide user sign up and login. After the user has successfully logged in, he can access a chat room, made with `socket.io`. I want to display user's name logged in through passport with socket.io. Here is my code:

server side **socket.io**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    io.emit('user connect'); 
});
```

client side

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function () {
            var socket = io();            
            socket.on('user connect', function () {
                $('#loggedUsers').append($('<li>').text(username)); <!-- right username is what I can't figure out how to do -->
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <ul id="loggedUsers" >
        <li> username.. </li>
        ...
     </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

And how people get that `html` file:

**EDIT:** Added middleware isLoggedIn, which I forgot to add earlier

```
router.get('/chatroom', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.user.username); //exactly what I want
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../views', 'chatroom.html'));
});
```

How to do that?

**NOTE**: my `chatroom.html` doesn't have form for username

---

Solved.
I discovered `passport.socketio` module and it did what I wanted. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport.socketio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js & Socket.io Adding Username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649705/node-js-socket-io-adding-username)

Answer (score 0):

`.emit` takes more than one parameter:

server:

```
io.emit('user connect', data);
```

client:

```
socket.on('user connect', function (data) {
// ...
```

As to how to get the data in the socket, here's a way to do it with JWT tokens, taken from [here](https://auth0.com/blog/auth-with-socket-io/):

Note: `jwtSecret` is a secret key that you store **on the server only**. Use the same one for the login and socket IO parts.

**Server side (on login):**

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

app.post('/login', function (req, res) {

  // validate the actual user
  var user = ...;

  // put user in a token signed with secret key
  var token = jwt.sign(user, jwtSecret, { expiresInMinutes: 60*5 });

  // send token as response or in any other way so the client can store it
  res.json({token: token});
});
```

Save the token that you get from your login response on the client to [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

**Server side (socket.io):**

```
var socketioJwt = require('socketio-jwt');

var sio = socketIo.listen(server);

sio.set('authorization', socketioJwt.authorize({
  secret: jwtSecret, // same secret key here
  handshake: true
}));

sio.sockets
  .on('connection', function (socket) {
     // will only connect if the user is a valid user
     var user = socket.handshake.decoded_token;
     // ...
  });
```

**Client side:**

Grab token from [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), then:

```
var socket = io.connect('', {
  query: 'token=' + token
});

socket.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('authenticated');
}).on('disconnect', function () {
  console.log('disconnected');
});
```

Please read the actual article for further information, this is the basic process.

Comment: After the user login, I did send the user profile in the token. But now I run `socket.io` from another file: `chatroom.html`. I still need to somehow reach the user data, but don't know how... (It's io.connect() on the client side). So I'm in starting position again :/

Comment: @PetarD. you need to save the token somehow (localstorage, sessionstorage, etc.) and then send it with your requests, so the server knows who the user is.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to do that. The user is already logged in using passport, I can't ask him to write his username and password once again on the chat room page

Comment: @PetarD. I've added the basics from the article I linked now, please do actually read it for further info.

Comment: How did you judge I didn't read it? I did several times. `query: 'token=' + token`  - token is parameter of the function `connect_socket`, which comes from a `POST` request, which I dont have in my html, and don't know how to do without it, and that is what I asked. Instead of copying code from the link you sent and being arrogant, you could've actually read my question.

Comment: I never said you didn't read it? The methods used in the article and that I copied are basic concepts which can be adapted to any situation, and yours is one of them. If you have trouble implementing any specific method, that's a different question alltogether. You're of course not supposed to just copy stuff, but adjust it to your use case, and the article itself explains those concepts next to the code that is an example implementation of the concept of JWT.

Comment: As is often the case - the linked page no longer exists and so is of no help to others looking for similar answers.