# Socket.io and React online users list not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I have an online users list for a chat app I'm making. When you log in it displays your username in the "Online Users" section, and this works fine for any amount of users so far. The problem comes when you log out:

- User 1 logs in and their username is added to the list.
- User 2 logs in and their username is added to the list.
- If user 1 logs out first, user 2's name gets removed and user 1's stays on the list, even when there are no logged in users
- If user 2 logs out first, their name gets removed and it functions as normal.

Here are my sockets in the backend:

```
const onlineUsers = [];
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.emit("online_users", onlineUsers);
  socket.join("public_chat");
  socket.in("public_chat").emit("online_users", onlineUsers);
  console.log(onlineUsers);

  socket.on("user_connected", (user) => {
    const userExists = checkUserArray(user, onlineUsers);
    !userExists && onlineUsers.push({ user, id: socket.id });
    console.log(onlineUsers);
    socket.in("public_chat").emit("online_users", onlineUsers);
    socket.emit("online_users", onlineUsers);
    console.log(`${user} is now online.`);
  });

  socket.on("user_disconnected", (user) => {
    console.log(user);
    const userExists = checkUserArray(user, onlineUsers);
    console.log(userExists);
    // finds the user that disconnected and removes them from the array
    if (userExists) {
      onlineUsers.splice(onlineUsers.indexOf(user), 1);
    }
    socket.emit("online_users", onlineUsers);
    socket.in("public_chat").emit("online_users", onlineUsers);
    console.log(onlineUsers);
    console.log(`${user} is now offline.`);
  });
});
```

Front end:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (Auth.loggedIn()) {
      const { data } = Auth.getUserInfo();
      socket.emit("user_connected", data.username);
    }
  }, []);

useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("online_users", (onlineUsers) => {
      setUsers(onlineUsers);
    });
  });

const logOutHandler = () => {
    const { data } = Auth.getUserInfo();
    console.log(data.username);
    socket.emit("user_disconnected", data.username);
    Auth.logout();
  };
```

It seems like the first logged in user's name gets "stuck" in the array.

Comment: There's code here left to the imagination, like `checkUserArray`. Can you provide a [mcve] please? `onlineUsers.push({ user, id: socket.id });` pushes an object to the array, then `onlineUsers.indexOf(user)` where `user` is the string username. That doesn't seem like it'll work. I'd use an object or map for this, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70792954/6243352).

Comment: @ggorlen `checkUserArray` returns `arr.some((x) => x.user === value)` , to find a user in the array. I ended up changing `indexOf` to `findIndex` and got it to work. Appreciate your help on my last question too, I'm a bit new to the site so I will keep the minimal reproducible example in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array of users have objects that contain the `username` and the `socketid`, but when you disconnect a user you use:

```
      onlineUsers.splice(onlineUsers.indexOf(user), 1);
```

`indexOf` is returning -1 because you user is a string and your array if filled with objects, this causes that the `splice` func always removes the last element in the array

Comment: Changed it to `onlineUsers.splice(onlineUsers.findIndex((x) => x.user == user),1);`
 and it works now, I was mixing up findIndex and indexOf. Thanks!